# PrintStream não grava acentos

Tags: java, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

vocês poderiam me ajudar numa questão?
Meu código não está passando acentuação para o arquivo de texto, mesmo passando o encoding.(Estou lendo ele em bloco de notas)

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
private String texto;
public void escrever(){


        try{
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("saida.txt","UTF-8");
            for(;;){
            System.out.print(">> ");
            this.setTexto(in.nextLine());

            if(texto.equals("::exit")){
                System.out.print("Saindo...");
                break;
            }else{
                ps.println(this.getTexto());
                }
        }

        }catch(FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
public String getTexto() {
    return texto;
}

public void setTexto(String texto) {
    this.texto = texto;
}
```

Me desculpem qualquer falha aqui. Ainda estou aprendendo a usar o site.
Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Você está inserindo essas informações pelo console do sistema operacional? Qual sistema operacional você está utilizando?

Comment: Estou inserindo pelo terminal do netbeans. E usando windows 10.

Comment: Qual é o texto que deveria ser impresso e como ele está sendo impresso? Você está abrindo pelo bloco de notas normal? Já verificou o encoding do editor de texto que está usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema não é causado pelo *character encoding* do `PrintScream`, mas pelo uso de diferentes *character encodings* entre o `Scanner` e o console/terminal que você está utilizando.

Para resolver esse problema você pode alterar o *encoding* utilizado pelo NetBeans. <del>Não tenho o NetBeans instalado aqui, portanto não posso testar mas</del>, segundo essa resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133195/how-to-change-file-encoding-in-netbeans/9085940#9085940), isso é feito dessa forma (Observação: isso não vai mudar apenas o *encoding* do console, mas também dos arquivos):

Vá na pasta do NetBeans, abra a pasta `etc`, abra o arquivo `netbeans.conf` e adicione a seguinte linha na variável `netbeans_default_options` (os valores dessa variável são demarcados por `""`, então verifique se o código abaixo foi colocado entre as aspas):

```
-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Reinicie o NetBeans.

Isso resolverá o problema quando você usa o terminal do NetBeans, porém não resolverá caso você use algum outro terminal, como o do Windows, por exemplo. Nesse caso, você deveria tentar alguma das duas seguintes soluções:

Informar o *character enconding* do console do Windows no construtor do seu `Scanner`. Exemplo:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "Cp850");
```

Uma desvantagem da solução acima é não ser portável.

Outra solução é utilizar a classe `Console` para ler a entrada de dados. Exemplo:

```
Console console = System.console();
String string = console.readLine();
```

A desvantagem desse método é não poder ser utilizado em IDEs.

Uma outra solução específica para o NetBeans é mudar o *encoding* utilizado pelo `Scanner` para `Cp1252`. Sendo assim, mude a declaração do seu `Scanner` para:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in, "Cp1252");
```

Comment: Deve ser algum problema no meu computador, porque nenhuma das soluções funcionaram. 
Com o python 3 eu não tinha esse problema todo e.e

Comment: @WallaceRocha esqueci de mencionar na minha resposta que linha `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` deve ser adicionada em uma variável específica, e não em um local qualquer do arquivo. Releia minha resposta e tente novamente, eu testei no NetBeans e funcionou! Além disso adicionei o *encoding* usado pelo NetBeans.

Comment: Antes eu não tinha entendido, mas agora fiz do jeito certo e funcionou.
Tentei também usar o eclipse, já neste, o problema não ocorreu.
Eu estava apenas tentando escrever um "Olá!" hahahaha
Obrigado!!!